# Why does scp seem to be failing?

Tags: debian, ssh, raspbian, scp

The copy seems to be failing. I was actually trying to copy a large directory and assumed it was failing because of the size, so I made a simple example with a small file, to demonstrate.

```
hduser@hnode0:~ $ ls -la myfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 hduser hdgroup 0 Aug  7 09:42 myfile
hduser@hnode0:~ $ scp myfile hduser@hnode2
hduser@hnode0:~ $ ssh hnode2
hduser@hnode2:~ $ ls -la myfile
ls: cannot access 'myfile': No such file or directory
hduser@hnode2:~ $ sudo find / -iname myfile
[sudo] password for hduser:
hduser@hnode2:~ $
```

Does scp write to a log ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `scp` is not failing, but it isn't doing what you expect it to do.

With

```
scp file user@host
```

you make a copy of `file` called `user@host` in the current directory (locally).

With

```
scp file user@host:
```

you copy `file` to the remote host `host` and place it in the home directory of `user`.

From the `scp` manual:

> The source and target may be specified as a local pathname, a remote host
>   with optional path in the form `[user@]host:[path]`, or a URI in the form
>   `scp://[user@]host[:port][/path]`.  Local file names can be made explicit
>   using absolute or relative pathnames to avoid `scp` treating file names
>   containing `:` as host specifiers.

Note that it is the `:` in the source or target filename operand that determines whether it specifies a remote or local location (in the first non-URI form of the argument).